# What do you do with todos?

Tags: verbs

I have a list of todos and I did what was required in those todos. For example, my todo list includes "grocery shopping" and I did that. How can I express that in a simple sentence?

Ideas:

- "I did my todos." or
- "I finished my todos." or
- "I processed my todos."

Comment: Out of context, "todos" sounds like a strange god, rhyming with "kudos."  I've more usually seen it as "to-do."

Comment: Indeed...at first blush I thought this was Spanglish. @TaliesinMerlin

Comment: Me duele todo el cuerpo.

Comment: It seems to me you "to-did" them.

Comment: My completed to-dos are to-dones.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin They sounded to me more like the things a dog might leave on the pavement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dictionaries don't document the usage you're describing. A "to-do list" is well-known, but a "[to-do](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to-do%20list)" is a bustle, stir, or fuss. Using synonyms like "tasks" or "jobs" would avoid the ambiguity.

Still, I had to see if the usage sometimes came up. [First, I went to the Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) and compared the collocations for the word following *todo* and *to-do*. Here's the result for the much more standard *to-do*:

[image]

By far, you are safest using "to-do list" rather than separating the expression. Only the 19 "to-do's"show signs of pluralization. Within the results, *to-do's* are mainly listed, tracked, or prioritized, not completed.

> Habaradas, Raymund B.  "Managing Social Enterprises in the Phillipines: Challenges and Strategies." *Arden*, Vol. 19, Iss. 2,  (2016): 39-56.
>
> "... journals, which can be used to take notes during meetings and listing down **to-do 's** ..."
>
> Trapani, Gina. "Organize Your Life With Free Online Tools." *PC World*, Vol. 26, Iss. 7; pg. 110-112.
>
> Before your brain bluescreens, take a moment to offload your entire to-do list into Remember the Milk (rememberthemilk.com), a fullfeatured task manager that categorizes and prioritizes **to-do 's** into convenient lists.

The 26 results for *to-dos* have about five results that describe completing the items in some way:

> 1         COCA:2014:MAG
>   PCWorld     you assign character attributes to your tasks and moving you up levels **as you complete to-dos.** On both the productivity and gamification fronts, it's slightly less compelling than
>
> 2      COCA:2012:MAG
>   Essence     the financial fitness challenge, let's make sure that **you have completed the essential to-dos**. Have you: # Ordered your free credit report from annualcreditreport.com? # Obtained
>
> 3      COCA:2008:MAG
>   Prevention  : Last year, they found that reaction time and **the ability to accomplish several to-dos** were strong in the middle of the day. TAP INTO IT: * Tackle
>
> 4      COCA:2008:MAG
>   Prevention  client or boss * Iron out a tough problem with your spouse **Tear through your to-dos**: Because of your mental quickness, this time of day is best for doing
>
> 5      COCA:2007:MAG
>   HarpersBazaar   again? '' I don't know. **I checked that off my list of to-dos**. And I can check off divorce, '' she says, giving a wry

So very occasionally people will use *to-dos* in the spirit of your first two examples with verbs like *to complete* and *to accomplish*. In comparison, "I processed my to-dos" sounds bizarre since "processed" does not mean finishing, completing, accomplishing, or even tearing through your to-dos.